# SolrCloud - Updates to schema or dataConfig

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

We have a SolrCloud managed by Zookeeper. One concern that we have is with updating the schema or dataConfig on the fly. All changes that we are planning to make is in the indexing server node on the SolrCloud. Once the changes to the schema or dataConfig are made, then we do a full dataimport.

The concern is that the replication of the new indexes on the slave nodes in the cloud would not happen immediately, but only after the replication interval. Also for the different slave nodes the replication will happen at different times, which might cause inconsistent results.

```
For e.g. 

The index replication interval is 5 mins.
Slave node A started at 10:00 => next index replication would be at 10:05.
Slave node B started at 10:03 => next index replication would be at 10:08.
```

If we make changes to the schema in the indexing server and re-index the results at 10:04, then the results of this change would be available on node A at 10:05, but in node B only at 10:08. Requests made to the SolrCloud between 10:05 and 10:08 would have inconsistent results depending on which slave node the request gets redirected to.

Please let me know if there is any way to make the results more consistent.

Comment: Are you using solr in master-slave mode or SolrCloud mode? There is difference in how updates are sent to slaves/replica in each mode.

Comment: We are using a SolrCloud mode. I am curious to know the differences that you have mentioned.

Comment: You can find it here: https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/201298317-What-is-SolrCloud-And-how-does-it-compare-to-master-slave-

Answer (score 0):

@Wish, what you are stating is not the behavior of a SolrCloud.

In SolrCloud indexing are routed to shard leaders and leader sent the copies to all the replicas.

At any point of time, if the ZooKeeper identifies that any of the replica is not in sync with leader, it will brought down to recovering mode. In this mode it will not serve any requests including the query.

P.S: In solr cloud configs are maintained at ZooKeeper and not at the nodes level.

I guess you are little confusing Solr Cloud and Master Slave mode, please confirm which one setup are you in?

Comment: Thanks Aneesh for your comment. We are using SolrCloud. As you suggested, the configs are getting changed in the Zookeeper (which is great).

But we want to maintain a dedicated indexing node in the cluster. The reason being that the indexing operation could sometimes take a long time to complete. So we do not want to load the indexing node by making it service requests.

Also during the indexing time, we want to make sure that all requests are serviced consistently. Do you have any suggestions on how this can be done.